# How to specify credentials username/password for elasticjs client?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticjs

Where can we specify username and password for the elasticjs (http://www.fullscale.co/elasticjs/) client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since elasticsearch itself does not support basic authentication, elastic.js does not provide a way to set this information in all clients.  The angular client recently gained support for passing the $http configuration object which allows setting custom headers (ie. the Authorization header used in http basic auth).  The jQuery and node clients do not support this at this time.

Comment: Does it make sense to file a request in github for this then or is it an unrealistic goal? I'm talking about the nodejs client. A lot of Elasticsearch as a service providers now use es-jetty or nginx to provide basic authN.

Comment: Please open a ticket, this is something we should get supported.